# Python-Networkx Graph Generating Function - For Loop

Tags: python, networkx

I have created a function to generate 100 random graphs in Networkx, and I want the output to be the graph list, as well as a couple of functions run on each generated graph (the diameter, transitivity, and average shortest path length). My output seems to be iterating on the same first generated graph, instead of through each sample graph generated. I am new to programming and believe it has to do with the structure of my loop, but appreciate any advice though I know the answer is likely basic. I am using Python 3.9 and NetworkX 2.5

```
 def random_networks_generator(n,p,num_networks=1, directed=False):
    Graph_list=[]
    dias=[]
    trans=[]
    avgpath=[]
    for num in range (0,num_networks):
        G=nx.gnp_random_graph(n,p,directed)
        D=nx.diameter(G)
        APL=nx.average_shortest_path_length(G)
        T=nx.transitivity(G)
        Graph_list.append(G)
        dias.append(D)
        trans.append(T)
        avgpath.append(APL)
    return Graph_list, dias, trans, avgpath 

random_networks_generator(793,.04,3,directed=False)

OUT: 

([<networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7fdc6889dbb0>,
  <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7fdc6889d0d0>,
  <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7fdc6889d160>],
 [3, 3, 3],
 [0.039558780162902554, 0.039558780162902554, 0.039558780162902554],
 [2.235259276242883, 2.235259276242883, 2.235259276242883])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a subtle bug, but the issue is this line:

```
G=nx.gnp_random_graph(n,p,directed)
```

The problem is that if you look at the signature for `nx.gnp_random_graph`, the third argument is the seed for the random number generator, not whether or not the graph is directed:

```
def gnp_random_graph(n, p, seed=None, directed=False):
    """Returns a $G_{n,p}$ random graph, also known as an Erdős-Rényi graph
    or a binomial graph.

    The $G_{n,p}$ model chooses each of the possible edges with probability $p$.

    Parameters
    ----------
    n : int
        The number of nodes.
    p : float
        Probability for edge creation.
    seed : integer, random_state, or None (default)
        Indicator of random number generation state.
        See :ref:`Randomness<randomness>`.
    directed : bool, optional (default=False)
        If True, this function returns a directed graph.
```

You are passing `False` as the seed (which is treated as the integer 0). Given a fixed seed like this, a (pseudo) random number generator will always generate the same sequence of random numbers, so the "random" graph will always be the same.

The fix is quite easy - just pass `directed=False` as a keyword argument. This is a good idea in general, as it prevents these issues which come from not memorizing the order of positional arguments:

```py
import networkx as nx


def random_networks_generator(n, p, num_networks=1, directed=False):
    Graph_list = []
    dias = []
    trans = []
    avgpath = []
    for _ in range(num_networks):
        G = nx.gnp_random_graph(n, p, directed=directed)
        D = nx.diameter(G)
        APL = nx.average_shortest_path_length(G)
        T = nx.transitivity(G)
        Graph_list.append(G)
        dias.append(D)
        trans.append(T)
        avgpath.append(APL)
    return Graph_list, dias, trans, avgpath 

results = random_networks_generator(793, .04, 3, directed=False)
for x in results:
    print(x)

"""
Output:
[<networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x7f61be2a8040>, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x7f61be28fd30>, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x7f61be1eeaf0>]
[3, 3, 3]
[0.03973988995344184, 0.040121944443041235, 0.03966888841109439]
[2.238010623256525, 2.2307373864750915, 2.22814844536156]
"""
```

I cleaned up your code a bit as well. Check out a PEP8-compliant linter such as [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) to develop good Python habits (or use an IDE like PyCharm which comes with built-in linting).

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for your help!